# Magento2 checkout page gets blank if item in cart more than 120

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, onepage-checkout, magento2.3.3, checkout-page

If I add more than 120 products to the cart, as I go on the checkout page it gets blank.
There is no error in the console and the body tag is blank in the browser. Magento version is 2.3.3 and on the checkout page, we are using one step checkout module provided by the OneStepCheckout team.

Can someone help in figuring this out?

Comment: In magento latest version,magento optimized the queries for cart items

Comment: But I need a solution for 2.3.3, I can't upgrade the Magento version to optimize the query.

Comment: If you have support for this module, like a warranty, for example, you can try asking them to solve this issue, since you have not posted the module's code, it is slightly difficult to guess what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Due to heavy amount of items in checkout onepage, it load more time , I have a solution but it partially helps you ,Go to

```
Store > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Option->Minimum (and Maximum) Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
```

Set maximum value then test .

Comment: Maximum value already defaults 10000.

Comment: yes set it to 100 or less than 100

Comment: But that's not solution for problem.